# How is it possible that CKQueryNotification reason is RecordUpdated but recordFields is nil?

Tags: ios, cloudkit, cksubscription, cknotification

`println("queryNotification.recordFields.keys: \(queryNotification.recordFields?.keys)")`

I do not catch how it this log possible? If I get a notification that record was updated, than I need at least one field that was changed, isn't it? Btw I am changing one field on an other device, so I do not see the reason why `recordFields` is nil, it should have at least one key-value.

[image]

```
enum CKQueryNotificationReason : Int {
    case RecordCreated
    case RecordUpdated
    case RecordDeleted
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Need to set `desiredKeys` when subscription being created.

`subscription.notificationInfo.desiredKeys = ["neededField"]`